# in WPF, how do i populate a DataGrid that is created in a external View outside the MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

i am very much new to WPF development and i have been trying to populate a DataGrid i have created in View. Following a tutorial the author seems to simply call the grid by name in his code and add the row that way, [this is his code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHIIF.png), but this wouldn't work for me as his DataGrid is defined in the `MainWindow.xaml` file while mine is defined in an external view or UserControl i believe its called,[This is the hierarchy of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGGqT.png)  just in case

this is the code of my View that is bound to the main Window

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pizzebest.MVVM.View.OrderCatalogView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pizzebest.MVVM.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
              d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="#161a29">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Order Catalog"
                   Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                   FontSize="28"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="20 10 0 10"/>
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Name="OrderCatalog">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15 5 0 5"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 2"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Oder N°" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Delivered By" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

here is the code in my MainWindow.xaml.cs that seems to me like the file where i should define all the different behaviours of my application (Buttons, Grids ...) :

```
using Pizzebest.Model.Actors;
using Pizzebest.Model.Orders;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace Pizzebest.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ArrayList orders = new ArrayList();
            Client Aimene = new Client("Aimene", "Hammani", "0748612464", new DateTime(), new Address(1,"Rue de Seine", 91260, "Juvisy"));
            Deliverer Gaspard = new Deliverer("Rafael", "Geslot", "0636371937", 1);
            orders.Add(new Order(1, new DateTime(),new DateTime(), State.PREPARING, Aimene, Gaspard));
            foreach (Order order in orders)
            {
                /* Here would go the reference to my DataGrid names OrderCatalog but that comes back with an error*/
                OrderCatalog.Items.Add(order);
            }
        }

        private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                this.DragMove();
            }
        }

        private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void Minimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code in my `MainWindow.xaml` just incase :

```
<Window x:Class="Pizzebest.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Pizzebest.MVVM.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pizzebest.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="920"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Opacity="0.98"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- TextBox Style-->
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#353340"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4b495c"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AntiqueWhite"/>

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Border Background="#11141f"
            CornerRadius="10">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Height="30">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="5 0" Background="#161a29" BorderBrush="#161a29" FontSize="14" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Exit_Click">X</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 0" Background="#161a29" BorderBrush="#161a29" FontSize="14" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Click="Minimize_Click">--</Button>
                <TextBlock MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Height="570">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                           Margin="30 0 0 0"
                           FontSize="22"
                           FontWeight="Bold">
                    PizzaBest
                </TextBlock>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                    <RadioButton Content="Orders"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Height="150"
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 IsChecked="True"
                                 Command="{Binding OrderViewCommand}"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Catalog"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Height="150"
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 Command="{Binding CatalogsViewCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding OrderTopBar}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton Content="Order"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                             
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding MainViewChange}"
                                 Command="{Binding OrderViewCommand}" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>


                    <RadioButton Content="Confirm Order"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                             
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 Command="{Binding OrderConfirmViewComand}"/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding CatalogTopBar}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton Content="Order Catalog"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding MainViewChange}"
                                 Command="{Binding OrderCatalogViewCommand}"
                                 Margin="0 0 0 0"
                                 Padding="0 0 0 10"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Client Catalog"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 Command="{Binding ClientCatalogViewCommand}"
                                    Margin="-10 0 0 0"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Delivery Catalog"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Grid.Column="2"
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 Command="{Binding DeliveryCatalogViewCommand}"
                                    Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Cashier Catalog"
                                 Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Grid.Column="3"
                                 Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                 Command="{Binding CashierCatalogViewCommand}"
                                    Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                </Grid>



                <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="1"
                                Padding="10"
                                Content="{Binding CurrentView}"
                                Background="#161a29"/>
                <!-- <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="0"
                                Content="{Binding CurrentOptions}"/>
               -->


            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

thank you in advance in helping me learn more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your UserControl should expose a bindable property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OrdersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Orders),
        typeof(IEnumerable<Order>),
        typeof(OrderCatalogView));

public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<Order>)GetValue(OrdersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OrdersProperty, value); }
}
```

to which the DataGrid in the UserControl's XAML is bound:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
          ...>
```

Then the MainViewModel class should have a similar property, e.g.

```
public ObservableCollection<Order> OrdersSource { get; } =
    new ObservableCollection<Order>();
```

to which the UserControl is bound:

```
<OrderCatalogView Orders="{Binding OrdersSource}"/>
```

The code in the MainWindow (or perhaps in MainViewModel) would initialize the `OrdersSource` property:

```
var vm = (MainViewModel)DataContext;

foreach (Order order in orders)
{
    vm.OrdersSource.Add(order);
}
```